# Единственное число?

Tags: единственное-множественное-число, определения

> *Я изучаю английский, французский язык**и**.*

> *Мы проплыли Южный и Атлантический океан**ы**.*

Обобщающие слова должны быть в ед. числе, верно?

Answer (score 3):

В данных предложениях применение множественного числа корректно:

*Я изучаю английский, французский язык**и**.

Мы проплыли Южный и Атлантический океан**ы**.*

Здесь важно подчеркнуть, как я думаю, не единение перечисляемых разновидностей объектов или явлений (тогда используется ед. число), а их множественность, отдельность.

[**ДВА ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЯ ПРИ ОДНОМ СУЩЕСТВИТЕЛЬНОМ**](http://rus-yaz.niv.ru/doc/rules-rosental/articles/194-dva-opredeleniya-pri-odnom.htm):

> **2.** Имя существительное ставится в форме множественного числа:
> **1)** если подчеркивается наличие нескольких предметов, например: биологический и химический методы; академическое и массовое издания произведений классиков; широкоэкранный и обычный варианты фильма; марганцевая и хромовая руды; соляная и серная кислоты; кузнечно-прессовый и сборочный цехи; золотая и серебряная медали...

Привожу по шесть **примеров из Нацкорпуса русского языка** в хронологическом порядке:

*А также изучаю английский и французский язык**и***. [А. Н. Толстой. Хождение по мукам/ Книга первая. Сестры (1922)]

*Он изучил английский и немецкий язык**и***. [Б. А. Пильняк. Большой шлем (1934)]

*Этот трактат сохранился, переведен на английский и французский язык**и***... [Г. С. Померанц. О роли нравственного облика личности... (1965)]

*Его книга «Цепь Плутона», вышедшая вторым изданием и уже переведенная на английский и французский язык**и**, богата не только наблюдениями...* [Вадим Орлов. Обзор // «Техника - молодежи», 1974]

*А почему же английский и французский язык**и** остались в этих странах государственными?* [В. А. Плунгян. Почему языки такие разные (1996)]

*Мы перевели сценарий на английский и немецкий язык**и***... [Алла Сурикова. Любовь со второго взгляда (2001)]

---

*И как только основные торговые пути пролегли через Атлантический и Индийский океан**ы**, Ганза, Венеция и Генуя перестали быть мировыми морскими державами.* [Л. Н. Скрягин. Книга о якорях (1973)]

*Финикияне открыли морские пути в Атлантический и Индийский океан**ы***. [А. И. Конюхов. Геология океана: загадки, гипотезы, открытия (1989)]

*...завершить поход предполагалось кругосветным плаванием через Индийский и Тихий океан**ы***. [Игорь Суханов, Наталья Шишкова. Подарок великого князя // «Родина», 1996]

*Дрейк пересек Тихий, Индийский и Атлантический океан**ы***...  [Г. П. Скарлато. Удивительная планета Земля. География: тайны и открытия (1997)]

*«Красин» был вынужден совершить переход через Тихий и Атлантический океан**ы***... [Виктория Волошина. Ледокол «Красин» хочет стать «Авророй» (2001) // «Известия», 31.08.2001]

*...вблизи Берингова пролива — ворот, связывающих Тихий и Северный Ледовитый океан**ы**, расположен остров Врангеля.* [Никита Овсяников. Остров Врангеля — наследие плейстоцена // «Наука в России», 2014]